# 1с8.2 - выводится лишняя пустая страница при печати внешней печ.формы

Tags: 1с

Сделал внешнюю печ. форму для документа инвентаризации ОС. Она состоит из множства  областей, и соответственно все они на первую страницу не вмещаются, да и не нужно. Требуется чтобы шапка была на 1ом листе, 2 и3 листе - таблица данных, подвал-на третьем листе.

Беда в том, что между листами у меня вставляется пустая страница - печатает 1ый - все ок, 2ой лисьт пустой, 3ий лист тот, который должен был печататься вторым и т.д. Т.е. кол-во страниц увеличивается вдвое. Даже если я буду использовать разрывы страниц, конец/начало страницы, разделители ситуация не меняется.

**Вопрос:** как не допустить того, чтобы система вставляла пустой лист после каждого напечатанного ? (каждый 2ой лист-пустой)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предугадать какие персональные настройки печати сделает пользователь невозможно, но вы можете поступить так: При формировании вашей печатной формы выводить горизонтальные разделители страниц после каждой части которая должна занимать один лист, а потом установить флаг АвтоМасштаб Табличного документа

```
ТабличныйДокумент.ВывестиГоризонтальныйРазделительСтраниц();

ТабличныйДокумент.АвтоМасштаб = Истина;
```

> ТабличныйДокумент.АвтоМасштаб
> (SpreadsheetDocument.FitToPage)
> ТабличныйДокумент
> (SpreadsheetDocument) АвтоМасштаб
> (FitToPage) Использование:
>
> Чтение и запись.  Описание:
>
> Тип: Булево.  Содержит признак
> автоматического масштабирования
> изображения при печати.
>
> Доступность:
>
> Тонкий клиент, веб-клиент, сервер,
> толстый клиент, внешнее соединение. 
> Примечание:
>
> Если признак установлен и табличный
> документ не помещается на одну
> страницу по ширине, то масштаб будет
> установлен таким образом, чтобы
> документ помещался на одну страницу по
> ширине.

Comment: не помогло к сожалению.

Comment: вы уверены что у вас притер по два листа не хватает?

Answer (score 1):

Была такая же проблема. Возможно дело в вертикальной границе страницы. Удалите несколько столбцов справа от печатной формы, на которых уже ничего не нарисовано. Мне помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Такая ситуация может возникать если есть строки с разными форматами строки (разной шириной колонок в строках). При этом сдвигается вертикальная граница страницы.
Надо выделить ячейку в строке, у которой так сдвинута вертикальная граница, и потом выделить и удалить лишние столбцы, чтобы вертикальная граница (обозначена пунктиром) выровнялась по всему документу